# Parameterized job using Uno-choice plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [Uno choice plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Uno+Choice+Plugin) to select parameter values based on previous selections.

(This plugin helped me to reduce parameter count. I can reuse same parameter for multiple platform based on the platform selection)

I used the groovy script to select parameter values.

But it takes too much time to load parameters.

Is there any way to speed up this process?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues and I was also using groovy scripts to cal shell scripts.I did the following things to reduce time:-

When you click on build with Parameters all task(scripts run at once together) are performed at once.
Use else conditions properly.
Also use Fallback script.

For eg:-

you have parameters such as

1) country 
2) state
3) city

each parameter depends on the previous values.

```
1) Try to only display contents on Jenkins front-end.(cat command).
2) Call a script if only it matches valid values in the previous parameter.   
3) minimum on the fly scripts.
4) optimize delays/sleep according to your load time.
5) Remove any extensions whether in chrome/Firefox.
5) Try using the same page in incognito mode.
6) If options are invalid through invalid option without going into any computation.
7) Uninstall plugin which are not required.
```

Will add more suggestions as I find.

I would request you also to please update if you find any method to optimize time.